# Why do we need EJB transaction instead of JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, transactions, ejb

I'm studying EJB and I have a hard time to understand why we need EJB transactions while we already have JDBC. All the necessary actions such as rollback, commit are already provided by JDBC.

Could anyone help me to understand this subject?

Thanks all.

Comment: May be Java EE documentation around it can help you  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncih.html

Comment: The reason is different levels of abstraction. You don't use JDBC directly when using EJB.

Comment: Hi MarkRotteveel, could you please elaborate a bit your response? Thanks.